# Pandas JSON Orient Autodetection

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to find out if Pandas.read_json performs some level of autodetection. For example, I have the following data:

```
data_records = [
    {
        "device": "rtr1",
        "dc": "London",
        "vendor": "Cisco",
    },
    {
        "device": "rtr2",
        "dc": "London",
        "vendor": "Cisco",
    },
    {
        "device": "rtr3",
        "dc": "London",
        "vendor": "Cisco",
    },
]

data_index = {
    "rtr1": {"dc": "London", "vendor": "Cisco"},
    "rtr2": {"dc": "London", "vendor": "Cisco"},
    "rtr3": {"dc": "London", "vendor": "Cisco"},
}
```

If I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records))
---
  device      dc vendor
0   rtr1  London  Cisco
1   rtr2  London  Cisco
2   rtr3  London  Cisco
```

though I get the output that I desired, the data is record based. Being that the default `orient` is columns, I would have not thought this would have worked.

Therefore is there some level of autodetection going on? With index based inputs the behaviour seems more inline. As this shows appears to have parsed the data based on a column orient by default.

```
pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_index))

          rtr1    rtr2    rtr3
dc      London  London  London
vendor   Cisco   Cisco   Cisco

pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_index), orient="index")

          dc vendor
rtr1  London  Cisco
rtr2  London  Cisco
rtr3  London  Cisco
```

Comment: FYI, the default `orient` is `columns` only because the default `typ` is `frame`. If you set `typ='series'`, the default `orient` becomes `index`. There is no level of autodetection, just how you want to reshape the data in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

When using `pd.read_json()` with `orient=None`, the representation of the data is automatically determined through `pd.DataFrame()`.

#### Explanation

The pandas documentation is a bit misleading here. When not specifying `orient`, the parser for 'columns' is used, which is `self.obj = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(json))`. So

```
pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records))
```

is equivalent to

```
pd.DataFrame(json.loads(json.dumps(data_records)))
```

which again is equivalent to

```
pd.DataFrame(data_records)
```

I.e., you pass a list of dicts to the DataFrame constructor, which then performs the automatic determination of the data representation. Note that this does not mean that `orient` is auto-detected. Instead, simple heuristics (see below) on how the data should be loaded into a DataFrame are applied.

#### Loading JSON-like data through `pd.DataFrame()`

For the 3 most relevant cases of JSON-structured data, the DataFrame construction through `pd.DataFrame()` is:

1. Dict of lists

```
In[1]: data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [9, 8, 7]}
  ...: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[1]: 
   a  b
0  1  9
1  2  8
2  3  7
```

2. Dict of dicts

```
In[2]: data = {"a": {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}, "b": {"x": 9, "y": 8, "z": 7}}
  ...: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[2]: 
   a  b
x  1  9
y  2  8
z  3  7
```

3. List of dicts

```
In[3]: data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 9}, {'a': 2, 'b': 8}, {'a': 3, 'b': 7}]
  ...: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[3]: 
   a  b
0  1  9
1  2  8
2  3  7
```

Comment: I agree ```columns``` is used by default like you write it. But I finally don't think there is any recognition mechanism like I experimented it in the last part of my answer.

Comment: there is no 'auto-detection' meaning no hidden black-box intelligence behind what the output is displayed, it's simply that the first dictionary had 0,1,2 index specified by the number of NON-nested JSON files, and the second one had "rtr#" as an index (at least as thought), but because it is a nested JSON the output was de-nested and the index was based on most bottom level dict or JSON object.  The most simple (non -nested) json is parsed first.

Comment: @LaurentB. @Paritosh Kulkarni
Thanks for your comments - I agree that “auto-detection” is not correct with regards to the param `orient`. I’ve adjusted my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

We can't speak of auto-detection, but rather of a **nested hierarchical structure** determined by a specified orientation or by the one used by default.

Moreover, it should be specified that we cannot use any data structure with a given orientation.

**Case 1 : Dataframes to / from a JSON string**

*`read_json` : Convert a JSON string to Dataframe with argument `typ = 'frame'`*

*`to_json` : Convert a DataFrame to a JSON string*

Orient value is explicitly specified with the Pandas `to_json` and `read_json` functions in case of `split`, `index`, `record`, `table` and `values` orientations.

This is not necessary to specify `orient` value for `columns` because orientation is columns by default.

**Case 2 : Series to / from a JSON string**

*`read_json` : Convert a JSON string to Series with argument `typ = 'series'`*

*`to_json` : Convert a Series to a JSON string*

If `typ = series` in `read_json`, default value for argument `orient` is `index`  see [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

When trying to convert a Series into a JSON string using `to_json`, default `orient` value is also `index`.

With the other allowed orientation values for a Series `split`, `records`, `index`, `table` argument `orient` must be specified.

**Resources**

We have some oriented structures in the comment section at this [github link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/json/_json.py) (have a look around line 680 in the `_json.py` file).

Note that there are no examples with `orient=columns` in the code comments on git-hub.
This is simply because in the absence of an orientation specification, `columns` is used by default.

**Clearer view of a nested hierarchical structure**

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

##### BEGINNING : HIERARCHICAL LEVEL #####

# Second Level - Values levels
d21 = {'v1': "value 1", 'v2': "value 3"}
d22 = {'v1': "value 3", 'v2': "value 4"}

# First Level - Rows levels
d1 = {'row1': d21, 'row2': d22}

# 0-Level - Columns Levels
d = {'col1': d1}

##### END : HIERARCHICAL LEVEL #####

print(pd.read_json(json.dumps(d))) # No need for specification : orient is columns by default

#                                     col1
# row1  {'v1': 'value 1', 'v2': 'value 3'}
# row2  {'v1': 'value 3', 'v2': 'value 4'}
```

**Be careful here**

Data structures cannot be used with any value given to the `orient` argument. Otherwise, a `builtins.AttributeError` exception should be raised (see the github link to see the diffrent structures).

```py
pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records))
#   device      dc vendor
# 0   rtr1  London  Cisco
# 1   rtr2  London  Cisco
# 2   rtr3  London  Cisco

#### Like orient is columns by default the previous is the same as following
pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records), orient='columns')
#   device      dc vendor
# 0   rtr1  London  Cisco
# 1   rtr2  London  Cisco
# 2   rtr3  London  Cisco

pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records), orient='values')
#   device      dc vendor
# 0   rtr1  London  Cisco
# 1   rtr2  London  Cisco
# 2   rtr3  London  Cisco

#### Dataframe shape is also important and exception could be raised

pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records), orient='index')
# ...
# builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records), orient='table')
# builtins.KeyError: 'schema'

pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records), orient='split')
# builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

**Is there an autodetection mechanism ?**

After some experimentations I can say now answer is no.

On github, `split` data shape is presented like the following :

```
data = {\
"columns":["col 1","col 2"],\
"index":["row 1","row 2"],\
"data":[["a","b"],["c","d"]]\
}
```

So let's do an experiment.

We will use `read_json` to read the data without filling in the orientation and see if the `split` shape is recognized.

Then we will read the data by entering the `split` orientation.

If there is an automatic shape recognition, the result should be the same in both cases.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

data = {\
"columns":["col 1","col 2"],\
"index":["row 1","row 2"],\
"data":[["a","b"],["c","d"]]\
}

json_string = json.dumps(data)
```

we print without filling in the orientation :

```py
>>> pd.read_json(json_string)
  columns  index    data
0   col 1  row 1  [a, b]
1   col 2  row 2  [c, d]
```

and now we print with filling in the `split` orientation.

```py
>>> pd.read_json(json_string, orient='split')
      col 1 col 2
row 1     a     b
row 2     c     d
```

Dataframes are different, Pandas do not recognize the `split` shape. `There is no automatic detection mechanism`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand every detail of a function call, I would suggest using VSCode and setting `"justMyCode": false` in your `launch.json` for debugging.

That being said, if you follow what's going on when you call `pd.read_json()` you'll find out that it instantiates a [JsonReader](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/io/json/_json.py#L760), before [reading it](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/io/json/_json.py#L898) which then instantiates a [FrameParser](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/io/json/_json.py#L1272) in turn parsed with [_parse_no_numpy](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/io/json/_json.py#L1314):

```py
def _parse_no_numpy(self):
  json = self.json
  orient = self.orient

  if orient == "columns": # default
      self.obj = DataFrame(
          loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
      )
  elif orient == "split":
      decoded = {
          str(k): v
          for k, v in loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float).items()
      }
      self.check_keys_split(decoded)
      self.obj = DataFrame(dtype=None, **decoded)
  elif orient == "index": # your second case
      self.obj = DataFrame.from_dict(
          loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float),
          dtype=None,
          orient="index",
      )
  elif orient == "table":
      self.obj = parse_table_schema(json, precise_float=self.precise_float)
  else:
      self.obj = DataFrame(
          loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None
            )
```

As you can see, like stated in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75362837/13525512), in terms of orientation:

```
pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_records))
```

is equivalent to

```
pd.DataFrame(data_records)
```

and

```
pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_index), orient='index')
```

to

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_index, orient='index')
```

So in the end it all boils down to how `pd.DataFrame` handles the passed list of dict.

Going down this hole, you'll find that the [constructor](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/core/frame.py#L475) checks [if the data is list-like](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/core/frame.py#L732) and then calls [nested_data_to_arrays](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L496) which in turn calls [to_arrays](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L790) that finally calls [_list_of_dict_to_arrays](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2e218d10984e9919f0296931d92ea851c6a6faf5/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L921):

```
def _list_of_dict_to_arrays(
    data: list[dict],
    columns: Index | None,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, Index]:
    """
    Convert list of dicts to numpy arrays

    if `columns` is not passed, column names are inferred from the records
    - for OrderedDict and dicts, the column names match
      the key insertion-order from the first record to the last.
    - For other kinds of dict-likes, the keys are lexically sorted.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : iterable
        collection of records (OrderedDict, dict)
    columns: iterables or None

    Returns
    -------
    content : np.ndarray[object, ndim=2]
    columns : Index
    """
    if columns is None:
        gen = (list(x.keys()) for x in data)
        sort = not any(isinstance(d, dict) for d in data)
        pre_cols = lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen(gen, sort=sort)
        columns = ensure_index(pre_cols)

    # assure that they are of the base dict class and not of derived
    # classes
    data = [d if type(d) is dict else dict(d) for d in data]

    content = lib.dicts_to_array(data, list(columns))
    return content, columns
```

The "autodetection" is actually the hierarchical handling of all possible cases/types.

Answer (score 0):

No, Pandas does not perform any autodetection when using the `read_json` function.

It is entirely determined by the `orient` parameter, which specifies the format of the input json data.

In your first example, you passed the `data_records` list to the `json.dumps` function, which is then converted it to a json-string. After passing the resulting json string to `pd.read_json`, it is seen as a  `record` orientation.

In your second example, you passed the `data_index` to `json.dumps` which is thenseen as a "column" orientation

In both cases, the behavior of the `read_json` function is entirely based on the value of the `orient` parameter and not by an automatic detection by Pandas.

Comment: Thanks. But passing in records without orient should not work as the default orient is columns.